# Running android with maven

Tags: java, android, maven, genymotion

This is one way of [running Android app with maven](https://github.com/nicokruger/android-maven-phonegap):

```
mvn -Dandroid.sdk.path=<YOUR_SDK_PATH> clean install android:apk
mvn android:emulator-start
mvn android:deploy
```

When  running emulator-start I get this error:

```
> [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Building Test App 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO]  [INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.7.0:emulator-start
> (default-cli) @ test --- [INFO] Android emulator command:
> ""/home/xybrek/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64/sdk/tools/emulator"" -avd
> default  [INFO] Waiting for initial device list from the Android Debug
> Bridge [INFO] Found 1 devices connected with the Android Debug Bridge
> [INFO] Starting android emulator with script:
> /tmp/android-maven-plugin-emulator-start.sh [INFO] Waiting for
> emulator start:5000 [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 8.701s [INFO] Finished at: Tue Apr 01 01:45:43 PHT
> 2014 [INFO] Final Memory: 13M/210M [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.7.0:emulator-start
> (default-cli) on project test: MojoExecutionException: Timeout while
> waiting for emulator to startup. -> [Help 1] [ERROR]  [ERROR] To see
> the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
> [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
> [ERROR]  [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible
> solutions, please read the following articles: [ERROR] [Help 1]
> http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

The emulator that is running is Genymotion. How can I make the app deploy in Genymotion?

**Error:**

> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal
>   com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.7.0:emulator-start
>   (default-cli) on project test: 
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
>   Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: 
>           at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.AbstractEmulatorMojo.startAndroidEmulator(AbstractEmulatorMojo.java:230)
>           at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.standalonemojos.EmulatorStartMojo.execute(EmulatorStartMojo.java:25)
>           at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
>           ... 19 more Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Timeout while waiting
>   for emulator to startup.
>           at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.AbstractEmulatorMojo.startAndroidEmulator(AbstractEmulatorMojo.java:216)
>           ... 22 more

Comment: Err, did you change `<YOUR_SDK_PATH>` ?

Comment: Yes, it points to the correct SDK I use with Eclipse, so I am sure that the SDK path is OK.

Comment: What happens if you use version 3.8.2 of the android-maven-plugin?

Comment: Here: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.8.2:emulator-start (default-cli) on project test: MojoExecutionException: Timeout while waiting for emulator to startup. -> [Help 1]

Comment: Have you a physical Android device connected to that machine, too?